# To login a site and after login redirect to a page in php curl

Tags: php, curl

To login to the site I have used this. But after successfully login that how can i redirect to a page as i want in the website.

For login by php curl i used this.

```
 $loginUrl = 'https://secure.propertyshark.com/mason/Accounts/logon.html';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email=myemail@hotmail.com&password=mypassword");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
$cookie = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookie.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    $answer = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        echo curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_setopt( $ch, 'http://www.propertyshark.com/mason/Property/619443/133-32-244-St-Queens-NY-11422/');
    echo $answer;
```

But i am not sure it is working or not, So i want how can i confirm about login and redirect to "'http://www.propertyshark.com/mason/Property/619443/133-32-244-St-Queens-NY-11422/" page.

Now i am using this, but not working.

```
<?php
$loginUrl = 'https://secure.propertyshark.com/mason/Accounts/logon.html';
$ch1 = curl_init();
$cookie = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookie.txt';
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email=myemail@hotmail.com&password=password");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);


$next_page = 'http://www.propertyshark.com/mason/Property/619443/133-32-244-St-Queens-NY-11422/';
$ch2 = curl_init();
$cookie = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookie.txt';
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $next_page);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$answer = curl_exec($ch2);
if (curl_error($ch2)) {
    echo curl_error($ch2);
}

echo $answer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cookie = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookie.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
```

you need to add cookie file opt and after login make another curl request to next page

LATER EDIT:

```
        $loginUrl = 'https://secure.propertyshark.com/mason/Accounts/logon.html';
        $ch1 = curl_init();
        $cookie = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookie.txt';
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

        ............


        $next_page = 'http://www.propertyshark.com/mason/Property/619443/133-32-244-St-Queens-NY-11422/';
        $ch2 = curl_init();
        $cookie = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookie.txt';
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $next_page);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        ............
```

Comment: should i add this to the script and create cookies.txt file ?

Comment: add to the script, no need to creeate cookies.txt ... is created automatically

Comment: How do i redirect the page ? i think, it is taking too much time or not working ? I have added the question with your script. please check

Comment: i updated the code ... i added `curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` for ssl

Comment: Now see i have added your answer. But it is not working. It is not logged in me to the page. I need redirect to the page after login. So that i am authenticate.

Comment: add `curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);`

Comment: Did you see my edited script and where to use the line. If in the ch1 part. should i use it for the ch2 part also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123911/discussion-between-catalinb-and-ranjit).